# Rails :respond_to javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my view: **(`show.html.erb`)**

```
 <%=link_to vote_for, vote_for_question_path(@question), :remote => true%>
```

This is the action that the link calls in the **`question_controller`**:

```
def vote_for
        @quest_vote_for = Question.find(params[:id])
        current_user.vote_exclusively_for(@quest_vote_for)

       @total_vote = current_user.total_votes
        respond_to do |format|
        format.js{}
        format.html
        end
    end
```

What I want, is to update the content of the show.html.erb after the link is clicked. (I am using ajax (`remote=>true`)). The show.html.page should update itself with the new value of `@total_vote`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add vote_for.js.erb, then add the following content to your file:

```
$("body").prepend("<h1><%= @total_vote %></h1>")
```

Comment: but i should replace $(''body'') with the selector that identifies the area i want to put the text in,right?

Comment: yes, you can do this: `$('div#total_vote').html('<%= @total_vote %>')`

Comment: Also you have to leave only the format .js {} and delete the line with the format.html, or will try to load a vote_for.html view.

Comment: What if you you want to catch HTML if js is disabled?